# How to apply a self-defined function to a specific column in R and avoid 'longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length' problem?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, mutate

Hello and good day to the one reading this!

I am trying to work with gridded data (e.g., lon, lat) and am currently figuring out how to 'round' my values to the closest values in a certain sequence.

For example, I first create a sequence for my gridded longitude values:

```
lon_seq <- c(seq(120.125, 125.525, 0.05)) # a sequence of even distribution from 120.125 to 125.525
```

Then, I define this function:

```
choose_lon <- function(lon_coord){
  lon2 <- lon_seq[which(abs(lon_seq - lon_coord) == min(abs(lon_seq - lon_coord)))][1]
  base::return(lon2)
}
```

To which if I run with a data I gathered from fieldwork would return a longitude value from the defined grid which is closest to my data (i.e., 123.3729° is closest to 123.375°):

```
> choose_lon(123.3729)
[1] 123.375
```

However, if I try to use it in a dataframe, it would return a `! longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` error. This is a sample data frame and the codes I tried to run:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  place = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
  code = c('1', '1', '2', '3', '2'),
  lon = c(123.4036, 123.7555, 120.6116, 124.6726, 122.3436)
)

df2 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lon2 = choose_lon(lon))
```

The codes above are to hopefully make an output with an additional column of longitude values which have been adjusted accordingly to my "gridded" data.

I have tried to follow the guide to "lengthen" my rows from [here](https://www.programmingr.com/r-error-messages/fixing-r-error-message-r-longer-object-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-shorter-object-length/) but it is to no avail so far.

I hope to kindly ask for your assistance on this matter.

Thank you very much and may you have a nice day!

Edit: I added the require code for the dplyr which is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The same error can be reproduced if you pass two values to your function

```
choose_lon(c(123.3729, 1233.4036))
#[1] 123.325
Warning messages:

1: In lon_seq - lon_coord :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In lon_seq - lon_coord :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

So this is what is happening in your code as well. More than one value are passed to the function where your function can only accept one value. To pass only a single value at a time in your function you can add `rowwise()` to the code.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lon2 = choose_lon(lon)) %>%
  data.frame() 

#  place code      lon    lon2
#1     A    1 123.4036 123.425
#2     B    1 123.7555 123.775
#3     C    2 120.6116 120.625
#4     D    3 124.6726 124.675
#5     E    2 122.3436 122.325
```

Or similarly, with `purrr::map_dbl`

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate(lon2 = purrr::map_dbl(lon, choose_lon))
```

Comment: Oh, I was not able to test the function if two coordinates are passed to it. I was not acquainted before with `rowwise()` and now thanks to it, the code works!

Thank you very much!